# How to draw color spectrum / space using CIE L*A*B values in c# or java?

Tags: c#, .net, color-space, spectrum

Any pointers or code samples or third party libraries on how to draw color spectrum using CIE L*A*B values using .net or java ?

We tried using WebGL but could draw using RGB values which would not display whole color space as with LAB values.

Thanks

Bhanu

Comment: What makes you think a rgb device could display all cie colors??

Comment: You cannot display the whole CIE L*a*b* colourspace or the whole visible spectrum on existing screens without compromises. No display technology is able to do that, for reference sRGB / Rec. 709 covers ±36.7% of the visible spectrum, DCI-P3 (newest Apple displays) covers ±45.4 and Rec. 2020 (the colourspace Wide Gamut HDR TVs adopts) covers ±70.7. Those computations are performed using Monte Carlo sampling and 10e6 samples using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour).